# Buffered reader test

Tags: java, testing, junit, tdd

I would like to test method which can take data from specific URL address and add it as a String to the ArrayList. The code for now:

```
public List<String> getListOfAirportsFromCsvAsAStrings(String urlAddress) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile.add(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile;
}
```

Is this method testable?

Comment: Nice answers, but the question itself is too broad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bad code that not be able proper unit tested, unit tests is about testing some code "unit" usually class in isolation, if this code need others classes to work you need to use mock classes and not real implementation.

In your case you should decouple code that goes to network from code that reading from stream.

```
 public class Parser {

    public  List<String> getListOfAirportsFromCsvAsAStrings(InputStream inputCsvData) {
        List<String> airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputCsvData))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile;
    }
}
```

I simplify your code (need java 7 or better). And this is test class for your parser:

```
import example.Parser;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

    public class ParserTest {

        @Test
        public void shouldReturnParsedTextFromInputFileStream() throws Exception {
            String text = "row1\nrow2\nrow3";
            InputStream inputFileStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
            Parser parser = new Parser();
            List<String> result = parser.getListOfAirportsFromCsvAsAStrings(inputFileStream);
            List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("row1", "row2", "row3");
            Assert.assertEquals(expected, result);
        }
    }
```

Assume you have **junit** library in your classpath.
P.S. In my opinion this code still smell and you need more refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

As is, the method is a pain to test. It's clearly not done in a TDD manner, as the tag says.

Do not create a HttpURLConnection in the code under test. Let the caller pass one in. That way you can mock it easily in testing and pass something that looks like a network connection but isn't the real thing. Keep external dependencies like the network out of unit tests. In production code, you can easily add connection pooling or other connection details if connections are created in one place instead.

Do not swallow exceptions. Any error will go unnoticed. Hours of debugging fun ahead. You cannot even test error behavior.

Is `airportsAsAStringFromCsvFile` a member variable? It probably should be a local variable, and you could make your function static.

You may also want to use try with resources.

As for TDD books, you could try:

- [JUnit Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394230) --- quite old, but may still have some good pointers
- [Effective Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182579)
- [Test Driven](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394850)

Comment: Ok thank you, do you know any good tutorial for TDD testing ? I saw some books, tutorials but examples are very simple not from real code... its hard for me to change thinking for TDD testing

Comment: @przemekost try this one https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Unit-Testing-JUnit-Mockito/dp/8393489393

Comment: @przemekost Updated my answer